# How do I export a data frame to Excel?

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to export a dataframe from R to excel. I am using the 'writexl' package but it does not seem to work.

The code is as following:

```
install.packages('writexl')
library(writexl)

write_xlsx(data_frame, "H:\\folder1.xlsx")
```

There does not seem to be any error produced and the code appears to have run, however when I look in 'folder1' the data_frame is not there.

Is there anything I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Have you tried the `xlsx` package? There it would be `write.xlsx(data_frame,"H:\\folder1.xlsx")`

Comment: It's easy to infer based on the name, but how did you make `data_frame`? Can you share a portion of it with `dput(head(data_frame))`, please?

Comment: Uh, your code does not involve a folder called `folder1`. It involves a *file* (confusingly) called `folder1.xlsx`. Are you sure you looked in the correct location? The file should be there (directly on the `H:` drive).

Answer (score -2):

I've found the openxlsx package to be easier to use than the xlsx package. It also doesn't have a java dependency. The main command for directly writing a data frame to an Excel file is write.xlsx. You can also create worksheets, do lots of fancy formatting and write multiple tables to a worksheet (see the vignettes here for some examples), but start with write.xlsx for the basic creation of Excel files.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with OP’s question, since OP is *not* using the ‘xlsx’ package …